# Segmentation fault on http.request

Tags: lua

Using the Lua Socket library I want to send a get request to an API, but everytime I do so it just returns segmentation fault and I can't figure out why!

```
local http = require("socket.http")

local data = {
    id = "1234"
}

local response = http.request {
    method = "GET",
    headers = {["Content-Type"]="application/json"},
    url = 'http://example.com/api/',
    data = data
}

local tokenResponse = json.parse(response.content)
```

Doesn't matter how I try it, always returns segmentation fault. Any clues why?

I'm running on Debian 8.6 Jessie.

Comment: Your code has already some problems: first you do not `require` the `json` module; second you do not correctly use the `socket.http` module (look at `sink` in http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html); third you have to encode your data in json before sending it and put it correctly in the request (look at `source` in http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html).

But the segmentation fault is usually obtained by using modules compiled for version of Lua that differs from the version of the interpreter. Check the lua interpreter path and the modules paths.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but a `GET` request does not use `Content-Type: application/json`.  You almost certainly want to use `Accept: application/json` to tell the destination server what you expect the response `Content-Type` to be.